# any word search Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wp-query, wpdb

By default, WordPress searches by keyword. What this means is that when passed the search query football boots, WordPress builds the following for the WHERE clause:

```
((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%football%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%football%'))

AND


((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%boots%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%boots%'))
```

but what if I would like to change this behaviour and I want it like following:

```
((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%football%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%football%'))

OR


((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%boots%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%boots%'))
```

Comment: I understand what you've written, but you forgot to state what your question is, please use the edit link under the list of tags to update it to include your question stated clearly. I've tried to add in the formatting to make this clearer and easier to understand

Comment: my question the default behaviour of wordpress search is to find the keyword Search but I want this behaviour not the default behaviour , difference is "AND" and "OR" 
How can I acheive the "OR" behaviour

((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%football%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%football%'))

OR


((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%boots%') OR

(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%boots%'))